# Remove div which have same class but not the one with specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html list which when someone click on .item class relavent id will append with layer=[id] to the closest div to clicked div which has class name as "layer". whenenve click on item class " === 
" this section will add.

I want to find all divs which has class "layer" to be remove when click on item div EXCEPT the one which has class "layer " and id as layer+[clicked item id]

please advice

Below is my html

```
<div class="seperator">
<div class="item" id="23"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="24"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="25"> ==== </div>
</div>
<div class="layer" id="later-23"> === </div>
```

===

===

```
<div class="seperator">
<div class="item" id="33"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="34"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="25"> ==== </div>
</div>
<div class="seperator">
<div class="item" id="43"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="44"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="45"> ==== </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".layer").not(this)` or `$(".layer").not("#layer"+this.id)` or `$(".layer").not("#later-"+this.id)` (to match your html) - hard to tell exactly what you're after

Comment: what you have done far?

Comment: @freedomn-m : please check my current code which only hide the div where I want to remove instead of hiding

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar please check updated question

Comment: This code `$(".layer").attr('id',"layer-"+ id);` changes *all* `.layer` divs - I doubt that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question here is working example for you. As you can see we catch a click event, then we do `if` check for `event.target.id` (the item you clicked) and the ids of all `.layer` items found and after the check we remove all the `.layer` elements except the one which has the same number in `id`

```js
 $('.item').click(function(e) {         
  $(".layer").each(function() {
   if(e.target.id != $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop()) {
     $( this ).remove();
    }    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="seperator">
<div class="item" id="23"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="24"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="25"> ==== </div>
</div>
<div class="layer" id="layer-23"> === </div>

<div class="layer" id="layer-24"> === </div>
<div class="seperator">
<div class="item" id="33"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="34"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="25"> ==== </div>
</div>
<div class="seperator">
<div class="item" id="43"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="44"> ==== </div>
<div class="item" id="45"> ==== </div>
</div>
```